# Display ngResource object in console.log

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app that is querying the [pokeapi](http://pokeapi.co/).

I'm using AngularJS ngResource in a factory to hit an endpoint and in my controller it's querying the data and the view is populating. The one thing I'm not able to do is log the actual object being returned so I can parse through it in the console.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('pokedexCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, searchCharacter) {

  $scope.search = function() {
    // get pokemon details
    var filteredSearch = $scope.searchCharacter.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');

    $scope.characters = [searchCharacter.get({
        value: $scope.searchCharacter
      }, function() {
        console.log('character retrieved' + $scope.characters);
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          alert('we are sorry but we could not find what you are looking for')
        }
      }
    )];
  };
});
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('searchCharacter', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/:value', {
    value: '@searchCharacter'
  }, {
    'query': {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
});
```

The only thing that I can get back in the console is:
`>character retrieved [object Object]`

How can I get the object tree in the console? [Image](http://blog.tadaweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.chrome.console.base64.png) of what I'm talking about

**Revised Controller**

```
app.controller('pokedexCtrl', function($scope, searchCharacter){

  $scope.search = function(){
// get pokemon details
var filteredSearch = $scope.searchCharacter.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'');

$scope.characters = [searchCharacter.get({
    value : filteredSearch
  }, function(){},
  function(response){
    if(response.status === 404){
      alert('we are sorry but we could not find what you are looking for')
    }
  }
)];

var pokemonObject = searchCharacter.get({value: filteredSearch}, function(value, responseHeader) {
  console.log('Pokemon Object: ', pokemonObject);
});

};
});
```

Comment: That what keeps stumping me, in the success function it should be getting that object. Trying to get the value but I'm still getting the same response.

Comment: It has the object - `console.log('character retrieved', $scope.characters)` is the correct syntax for the console.

Comment: In running the $http in the controller before moving over to ngResource it brought back the object tree with above console.log. But, how would you get the object tree using the ngResource?

Comment: Just the same.. http://plnkr.co/edit/oFtG1JbfKU6V9BPLlPBS?p=preview

Comment: @JesseBuitenhuis Thanks for the Plunker, I've revised the controller to include a working object tree return. However part of me feels like I've implemented incorrectly/poorly.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do with the `$scope.characters = []` part, and what do you feel is poorly implemented? Could you share your plunker?

Answer (score 0):

your console log isn't returning the object because you are parsing it as a string with the `+`

```
console.log('character retrieved' + $scope.characters);
```

If you want to return an object, you need to separate with a comma

```
console.log('character retrieved', $scope.characters);
```